# How to get the strings till end of line after the match from a multiline string

Tags: python, python-3.x

From a multi line string, how to get the strings after the last match till end of line?

In this example, I need only the `some failure message` without the following line(s) ?

```
>>> my_string="hello world \n error: this can be anything \n another line \n error: some failure message here \n any line"
>>> print(my_string.rsplit("error:",1)[1])
 some failure message here 
 any line
```

Comment: maybe first split text into lines and later use `pos = line.find("error:")` on every line and when you get value bigger then -1 then use `line[pos + len("error:"):]`

Comment: or `rsplit("error:", 1)[1].split("\n", 1)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

After calling `rsplit()`, call `splitlines()` and get the first line.

```
error_all = my_string.rsplit("error"", 1)[1]
error_lines = error_all.splitlines()
error_msg = error_lines[0]
print(error_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rfind` and `find` methods:

```
my_string = "hello world \n error: this can be anything \n another line \n " \
            "error: some failure message here \n any line "

word = 'error: '
start = my_string.rfind(word)
end = my_string.find('\n', start)
print(my_string[start + len(word):end])
```

Second argument of the `find` lets you specify fromwhere you want to "find".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with regex

```
import re

regex = r"error:.*"

test_str = ("hello world\n"
    "error: this can be anything\n"
    "another line\n"
    "error: some failure message here \n"
    "any line")

match = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)[-1]

print(match)

>> error: some failure message here
```